# Azure Cosmos DB - V2 Indexing Policy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are having performance issues when using the COUNT function on a container with ~500,000 items.

This query...

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c where c.batch = 'TestBatch'
```

...is slow, and returns a count of 438797, consuming 13438 RUs. I'm running this query using V3 of the Cosmos DB SDK, using a FeedIterator and passing in a single partition key.

I’ve noticed in a few other posts, mentions of a “V2” indexing policy, which apparently includes some significant performance improvements.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54931244/2913
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100486/2913

**How can I check what version of the policy my database is using, and if it’s not V2, how can I upgrade to this?**

Comment: I mean, what do you expect if your query returns 440k items?

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how are you consuming that query? And is `batch` your partition key in the collection?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I'm using a FeedIterator and setting the partition key via the QueryRequestOptions that I pass in. "batch" isn't the partition key.